# JAVA Messaging Service

Tags: java, messaging

I am looking to exchange messages between Java classes which are running as part of different Java processes (or JVMs). For example: a Java class which has detected an event will wrap it up as a Java message and send it to an event handling class running inside a different Java process.

What's a simple and well established approach to such messaging? Since the messaging will *always* be between Java classes, I do not want the overhead of XML SOAP or the complexity of Corba.

Thanks
Neel

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution would be JMS. But it seems its very heavy weight for your needs. I would suggest to write a small TCP layer using MINA or something and build a custom solution over it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Spring-Integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/). It has options for both external and internal messaging. You can use JMS, TCP packages, all kinds of stuff.

Comment: How complex is the Spring-Integration framework? I do not need the full Spring MVC containers.

Comment: It operates at the normal Spring bean level, but introduces a bunch of message processing components and whatnot. It's not really based on Spring MVC, just the core Spring libraries. You'll probably be interested in the various adapters and the transport options they provide.

Comment: Spring-Integration is definitely interesting. Any idea as to how does it compares with the Apache Camel wrt complexity and ease of use?

Comment: I haven't used Apache Camel, so I can't speak to it.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question but for clarification I will just shoot: Can Spring-Integration be used for communicating across POJOs which are running inside different JVMs?

Comment: Yes, but the POJOs will have to be wrapped inside spring context files. In fact, a major goal of spring integration was to eliminate the need for the POJOs to know anything about the messaging system. With proper configuration, the message will appear to be a normal method call to the POJO, the input being a simple object and the output another java object. You'll just configure the appropriate outbound gateway in one context and the corresponding inbound gateway in the other.

Comment: Thanks; but, it sounds like an overkill, isn't it? I'm looking for something very simple where I just need to implement the threads logic (how each threads acts upon a message) and the type/content of the messages.

Answer (score 0):

One option is [Jini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jini), now referred to as Apache River.

Jini will help with discovery and serialization. It allows you to call a method in one class from another class running in a different JVM.

Jini is fairly elegant. It's easy to specify which methods are exposed to remote callers. Exceptions from the called method are communicated as exceptions to the caller. Discovery supports painless redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the asynchronous aspect, simple [RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) will do.

Comment: messages will be sent asynchronously by various event detectors.

Comment: can still be done asynchronously, even with rmi.  your listeners just need to register with some sort of broadcaster.

Comment: Yes, but then it gets more complicated again.